# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

Tags: proxy, sublimetext3

I am trying to configure sublime text 3 with AngularJS. I copied the message i found on the internet for sublime text 3 to the console to install the package controller:

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'df21e130d211cfc94d9b0905775a7c0f' + '1e3d39e33b79698005270310898eea76'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1248, in do_open
  File "./python3.3/http/client.py", line 1065, in request
  File "./python3.3/http/client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
  File "./python3.3/http/client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
  File "./python3.3/http/client.py", line 906, in _send_output
  File "./python3.3/http/client.py", line 844, in send
  File "./python3.3/http/client.py", line 822, in connect
  File "./python3.3/socket.py", line 417, in create_connection
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 156, in urlopen
  File "./python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
  File "./python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 487, in _open
  File "./python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
  File "./python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1274, in http_open
  File "./python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1251, in do_open
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I have found different solution on the Internet, but nothing worked for me. I would appreciate if u could help me. Thank you!

Comment: what build/version of ST3 are you using? The latest at the time of writing (3126) contains a built in way to install Package Control in the Tools menu -> Install Package Control… - might be worth trying, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I am using 3126 version. I'll try ur advice.

Comment: I don't have any Install Package Control in my tools menu

Comment: could it be already installed? the menu item isn't shown in such cases. If you open Tools -> Command Palette, are there any entries for Package Control?

Comment: Ok i installed packages here for angularjs but in the tutorials i followed i need to install packages for sublime text in the manner described above